# Issues While Load Testing Using WAPT Pro 3.1

Tags: load-testing, wapt

I am using WAPT Pro3.1 (Trial Version) to do load testing (Performance Test)

While creating a profile under a scenario, I am facing a problem... 'connection was reset' error is coming if a page which I am trying to record takes longer time to load.(This timeout is happening within 2 mins after the page is clicked)

The page which is clicked to record works fine when I use it outside this tool and set_time_limit(0) is set in this particular page.

But 'Maximum time of waiting for server operation' parameter has been been reset to 1000 secs in WAPT Pro.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

"connection was reset" typically means the TCP connection was torn down by the other side (Server in this case).

So this typically mean the server side ran into some issues and it can't serve the request within a time limit and tear down the connection.

If you use [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com) performance test platform, not only will you find the test scenarios are easier to do, you will be able to get much fast help.